# how can define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE

Tags: linux

/usr/bin/python3.8 "/home/sultancode/Desktop/HEART DISEASE PREDICTION/Heart Disease Prediction/accounts/migrations/0001_initial.py" Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/home/sultancode/Desktop/HEART DISEASE PREDICTION/Heart Disease Prediction/accounts/migrations/0001_initial.py", line 8, in <

Comment: [How to permanently set environmental variables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/117467/306529)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unix Bash shell:

```
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=mysite.settings
```

On the server:

```
import os

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'mysite.settings'
```

See the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/settings/) for more info